# How to prove the Vandermonde's determinant for a $3\times 3$ matrix when rows and columns have been swapped?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant, math-history

The problem is as follows:

> The following determinant is named after french mathematician Alexandre-Théophile Vandermonde who lived in the late 18th century.
>
> Prove this determinant
>
> $\left|\begin{matrix}
> 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
> a & b & c\\ 
> a^2 & b^2 & c^2
> \end{matrix}\right|=(b-a)(c-b)(c-a)$

What I've attempted to do was to use this well known identity on matrices:

$\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
a & b & c\\ 
a^2 & b^2 & c^2
\end{matrix}\right|=1\left|\begin{matrix}b&c\\b^2&c^2\end{matrix}\right|-1\left|\begin{matrix}a&c\\a^2&c^2\end{matrix}\right|+1\left|\begin{matrix}a&b\\a^2&b^2\end{matrix}\right|$

Then working in the right side of this equation I'm getting:

(Here I'm using the notation of capital $V$ for Vandermonde's determinant)

$V=(bc^2-cb^2)-(ac^2-ca^2)+(ab^2-ba^2)$

Factoring the common terms I'm getting

$V=bc(c-b)-ac(c-a)+ab(b-a)$

But now what? I'm stuck, what else should it be done here? Can someone help me here on how to prove this determinant? Could it be that my method wasn't that right? Please help.

Comment: maybe you can see by expanding their answer that it is the same

Comment: @korone Expanding what answer?. I can't do this by my own. Perhaps can you help me further?

Comment: I am sure you can multiply out your formula for $V$ on your onw,  and the result you want to get, too. They coincide, right?

Comment: Why don't you take the discriminate using the second row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the first column from the second column and factor out a common term from the second column.

$\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
a & b & c\\ 
a^2 & b^2 & c^2
\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\ 
a & b-a & c\\ 
a^2 & b^2-a^2 & c^2
\end{matrix}\right|=(b-a)\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\ 
a & 1 & c\\ 
a^2 & b+a & c^2
\end{matrix}\right|$

Now do that again.

$(b-a)\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\ 
a & 1 & c\\ 
a^2 & b+a & c^2
\end{matrix}\right|=
(b-a)\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
a & 1 & c-a\\ 
a^2 & b+a & c^2-a^2
\end{matrix}\right|=
(b-a)(c-a)\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
a & 1 & 1\\ 
a^2 & b+a & a+c
\end{matrix}\right|$

Last, subtract the second column from the third column

$=
(b-a)(c-a)\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
a & 1 & 0\\ 
a^2 & b+a & c-b
\end{matrix}\right|$

That final discriminant is obviously $c-b$, and you're done.

Comment: Yay your method is very nice. I posted an answer which somewhat is similar to yours. But yours I believe it is more intuitive. Thus i'm accepting your answer. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
V=bc(c-b)-ac(c-a)+ab(b-a) = - (a - b)(a - c)(b - c).
$$

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain **how did you arrived to that conclusion** because I can't. Please help me with this.

Comment: First of all, check the identity by **multiplying out** both sides. Then you have solved your question. If you also want to know how to find this factorization, try to **factor  out** $(b-a)$ first.

Comment: I know what you mean but it isn't exactly the proof which I was looking. What I was intending to look for was a method on how to prove this without comparing $(b-a)(b-c)(c-a)$. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, sure. Factor out $(b-a)$ from your expression for $V$ first, as I said. Then it is obvious.

Comment: Gee I'm still unable to do that. I mean $(b-a)$ appears only once for $V$ how can it be factor out?. Can you add this in your answer as an additional hint?. I'm sorry but maybe I'm not good with algebraic manipulations.

Comment: We have $V=(b-a)(c^2-bc-ac+ab)$ and then $V=(b-a)(c-b)(c-a)$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove this identity might use some properties of matrices:

$V=\left|\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{matrix}\right|$

Multiply the first row by $a$ and subtract from the second row, anotate this result as the new second row. Use the original second row and multiply it by $a$ and subtract from the third row, anotate this result as the new third row.

$2R-1R\times a, 3R-2R\times a$

$\left|\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\0&b-a&c-a\\0&b^2-ab&c^2-ac\end{matrix}\right|$

Then using the known identity:

$1\left|\begin{matrix}b-a&c-a\\b^2-ab&c^2-ac\end{matrix}\right|-1\left|\begin{matrix}0&c-a\\0&c^2-ac\end{matrix}\right|+1\left|\begin{matrix}0&b-a\\0&b^2-ab\end{matrix}\right|$

This becomes into:

$V=1\left|\begin{matrix}b-a&c-a\\b^2-ab&c^2-ac\end{matrix}\right|$

$V=1\left|\begin{matrix}b-a&c-a\\b(b-a)&c(c-a)\end{matrix}\right|$

$V=1 (b-a)(c-a)\left|\begin{matrix}1&1\\b&c\end{matrix}\right|$

$V= (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)$

Thus that's it how it can proved. This works using the identity of factoring terms from the columns in the Vandermonde's matrix.